# How to insert and update data by KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

Here my json data which return from server end.
I have populated my html table with below sample json by KnockoutJS foreach binding,

```
{
 { "Id": "12345", "Name": "Acme Widget 1", "Price": "£25.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
 { "Id": "67890", "Name": "Acme Widget 2", "Price": "£28.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
 { "Id": "11123", "Name": "Acme Widget 3", "Price": "£15.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
 { "Id": "14156", "Name": "Acme Widget 4", "Price": "£33.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
}
```

I am using SignalR which notify me when data change in table giving json as follows,

```
 { "Id": "11123", "Status": "Out of Stock"  }   /* Out of Stock message */
 { "Id": "12345", "Price": "31.45" }            /* Price Change message */
```

And new data arrive notified by KnockoutJS,

```
{ "Id": "14177", "Name": "Dubli Widget Bazar", "Price": "£102.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
```

Now tell me how could perform insert or update existing data. See this two data having id `11123 & 12345` which already exist in table, so in this case I would like to update that data just find by id and update status and price.

The last one data notified by `SignalR` which is new so I will insert that data to my table which was populated by `KnockoutJS foreach binding`.

I am new to Knockout. So guide me how to update existing data and also insert new one if not found. I like to find first by id... If found then update existing one or if id is new then will insert as new data. The moment I will update data or insert then table should reflect the change. Please help me with sample code.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me if you can get the last one on your JS, if so you could simply push it into your array of products (in the right JSON format).

Comment: i try to know how could i find data by id....if not found then i would push but if found then i will update status or other field. i was looking for help because i do not know how to find data in observable array. how to update data in observable array......so just wonder if some could guide me with small sample code. thanks

Comment: Finding an item in an observable array is the same as finding data in a regular array. Just don't forget to call the observable as a function to get the underlying array.

Comment: If you're binding to properties of these objects then they will only update (automatically) if you make those properties observables. Nobody can really answer your question right now. Please share more code like your HTML and view model.

Comment: apologized....can u come with a small example which would give me clue to finish the task?

Comment: check this jsfiddle.net/62Ls6x9n/159 . everything cool i can post it as answer,

Comment: @supercool can't we add new data directly instead of inserting one-by-one. your below code inserting data iterate in loop obe-by-one `self.AddNewData= function() {
        //alert("add");
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(NewData, function (item) {
           //Have a duplicate id check before push
            self.Stocks.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(item));
        });
    }`

Comment: yes you can't . note this you can push a `instance` and assign `list` to observableArray .

Comment: @SuperCool yes possible i got it. `self.Stocks.push.apply(self.Stocks,NewData);` without iterate we can insert multiple or single json element to observable array. need your suggestion.

Comment: if you are using `push.apply` you can push all at a time try this `self.Stocks.push.apply(self.Stocks,ko.mapping.fromJS(NewData)());` . cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here i am pasting answer got from @SuperCool. thanks

### js file dependency

```
jquery file need to add with version 1.6.4
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js

<input type="button" value="Add New Data" data-bind="click:AddNewData"/>
<input type="button" value="Update Data" data-bind="click:UpdateData"/>
<br>
<br>
<table class="imagetable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:Stocks">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <Span data-bind="text:Id" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <Span data-bind="text:Name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <Span data-bind="text:Price" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <Span data-bind="text:Status" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

var data = [{
    "Id": "12345",
    "Name": "Acme Widget 1",
    "Price": "£25.99",
    "Status": "In Stock"
}, {
    "Id": "67890",
    "Name": "Acme Widget 2",
    "Price": "£28.99",
    "Status": "In Stock"
}, {
    "Id": "11123",
    "Name": "Acme Widget 3",
    "Price": "£15.99",
    "Status": "In Stock"
}, {
    "Id": "14156",
    "Name": "Acme Widget 4",
    "Price": "£33.99",
    "Status": "In Stock"
}];

var NewData = [{
    "Id": "99999",
    "Name": "HSL Limited",
    "Price": "£78.99",
    "Status": "In Stock"
}];

var UpdateData = [{
    "Id": "11123",
    "Name": "",
    "Price": "",
    "Status": "Out of Stock"
}, {
    "Id": "12345",
    "Price": "31.45",
    "Name": "",
    "Status": ""
}]

var appViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Stocks = ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
console.log(self.Stocks())
   self.AddNewData= function() {
        //alert("add");
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(NewData, function (item) {
           //Have a duplicate id check before push
            self.Stocks.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(item));
        });
    }
   function test(val,old){
       return val == "" ? old : val ;
   }
    self.UpdateData = function() {
         ko.utils.arrayForEach(UpdateData, function (mainitem) {
             ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Stocks(), function (subitem) {
               if(mainitem.Id===subitem.Id()){
                 subitem.Price(test(mainitem.Price,subitem.Price()));
                 subitem.Name(test(mainitem.Name,subitem.Name()));
                 subitem.Status(test(mainitem.Status,subitem.Status()));
                }
             });
        });
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());

table.imagetable {
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #999999;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.imagetable th {
    background:#b5cfd2 url('cell-blue.jpg');
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999;
}
table.imagetable td {
    background:#dcddc0 url('cell-grey.jpg');
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//main
var data = getLast();
var item = findById(3);
if (item === undefined)
    insert(data);
else 
    update(item, data);

//loop (if necessary)
for (var i = 0; i < self.items().length; i++) {
   //loop code through obserbble array
}

//insert
function insert(data) {
    self.items.push(data)
}

//update
//you could copy all properties if they are not binded
function update(old, _new) {
    old.p = _new.p;
    ...
}
//you could only reference the new data if they are binded
function update(old, new) {
    old.p(new .p); //maybe "old = new works", not sure
    ...
}
```